# Display the terms or product attributes for a specific product category(woocommerce)

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I have been researching all over the net and forums regarding my question but I can't seem to produce the correct results. Basically I'm trying to display the terms or product attributes for only a specific product category.

Here is the code I have been working on.

```
<fieldset class="liquor-types-control filter-controls" >

    <?php 

    $terms = get_terms( 'wine', /*<--Product Category */ 'pa_liquor-types' /* <--Product Attribute */);
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    ?>

    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo "." . $term->slug ?>"  /> 
        <?php echo $term->name ?>
    </label>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


</fieldset>


(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid taxonomy.
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you share a `var_dump($terms)` so we can see the format of the data? Also, what output are you getting? Any errors? Make sure to set error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: updated my question with additional details

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The `var_dump` is showing that you are using taxonomies on WordPress. While I don't have experience directly with Wordpress, [the Wordpress site docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) say:

> Prior to 4.5.0, the first parameter of get_terms() was a taxonomy or
>   list of taxonomies:
>
> Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument
>   in the $args array:

[From the function reference:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term)

```
$term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
```

Gives you term slug: e.g.: term-slug-example

```
$slug = $term->slug;
```

Gives you term name: e.g. Term Name Example

```
$name = $term->name;
```

First, make sure you are using the correct version - you are using the syntax from prior 4.5.0

Second, the error is saying that the taxonomy `pa_liquor-types` is invalid. You need to check where this is being defined.

Check your `create_initial_taxonomies()` function syntax and post it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'wine', 'pa_liquor-types');

foreach($terms as $term) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo "." . $term['slug'];?>"/>
    <?php echo $term['name'];?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Tried your solution but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Use ; after $term->slug and $term->name.

```
 <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"  /> 
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </label>
```

Comment: Please check your code, your code having mistakes. The  statement should end with ; and why you are using <?php echo "." . $term->slug ?>.  This is not correct.

Comment: And also get_terms( 'wine'); is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work, I tried your solution

Answer (score 0):

Get terms of wine and liquor-types seperately, merge them to single array $terms and loop through that array to get all terms. Hope it helps, haven't tested the code yet.

```
<fieldset class="liquor-types-control filter-controls" >

    <?php 
    global $post;
    $terms_wine = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'wine');
    $terms_liquor = get_the_terms(get_the_ID,'pa_liquor-types');
    $terms = array();
    foreach($terms_wine as $wine){
        array_push($terms,$wind);
        }
    foreach($terms_liquor as $liquor){
        array_push($terms,$liquor);
        }


    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    ?>

    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo "." . $term->slug ?>"  /> 
        <?php echo $term->name ?>
    </label>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


</fieldset>
```

Comment: Not sure if you have the $post or not, if not the get the id of current product whose terms you want to list and replace $post by the id of product.